# Python no longer works - "site" import fails

Tags: python

After the weekend, certain programs on my computer have stopped functioning normally. Most important is Scrapy and Python which I need for a specific task. Now when I run Scrapy, I get an error. I tried uninstalling and re-installing but this problem persists. Please help. I am using Windows 7 (which I am required to use).

```
C:\Users\abc> scrapy -help
ImportError: No module named site

C:\Users\abc>python
ImportError: No module named site

C:\Users\abc>python -v



# installing zipimport hook

import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
ImportError: No module named site

# clear __builtin__._
# clear sys.path
# clear sys.argv
# clear sys.ps1
# clear sys.ps2
# clear sys.exitfunc
# clear sys.exc_type
# clear sys.exc_value
# clear sys.exc_traceback
# clear sys.last_type
# clear sys.last_value
# clear sys.last_traceback
# clear sys.path_hooks
# clear sys.path_importer_cache
# clear sys.meta_path
# clear sys.flags
# clear sys.float_info
# restore sys.stdin
# restore sys.stdout
# restore sys.stderr
# cleanup __main__
# cleanup[1] zipimport
# cleanup[1] signal
# cleanup[1] exceptions
# cleanup[1] _warnings
# cleanup sys
# cleanup __builtin__
# cleanup ints: 6 unfreed ints
# cleanup floats
```

Comment: Have you run chkdisk (or fsck on linux) and checked the SMART logs for hardware errors?

Comment: Ex Umbris, could you elaborate? I am not familiar with chkdisk or SMART logs.

Comment: Run `set` and post the contents of the `PYTHONPATH` variable.  That error usually indicates that Python can't find the directory it stores its libraries in.

Comment: What is the output from running '%PATH%' and '%USERPROFILE%' on the command line? This looks like an issue of the path not being set correctly or the user directory not being defined correctly.